# How with jQuery catch if login session was expired in laravel app?

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel 8 app I use jQuery 3.5.1 and wonder if there is a way in case if login session was expired to catch this error in 1 place to make logout from the app?

Just something as I have in vuejs :

```
this.$http.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (error) {

    return new Promise(function (/*resolve, reject*/) {
        if (typeof error.response.status !== 'undefined' && error.response.status === 401) {
            self.$store.dispatch('logout')  // DEBUGGING
            self.showPopupMessage('Access', 'Not authorized !', 'warn')
            ...
        }
```

Comment: [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)?

Comment: I which place? On any ajax request ? Maybe there is 1 place where I can do it, like I did in vuejs with sample code

Comment: Where ever you need. In try block you check if you have satisfying data, if not throw error and in catch block do what you need to do with error.